# Typings in vscode, how to show the whole type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, zod

It will be great to have an option to expend the hover canvas when you want to see the whole type.

Comment: Please clarify the **question** you are asking. Otherwise, it may be to your benefit to create a question asking about this topic, and then answering your own question, especially if you think it would be helpful.

Comment: ok, is it good now ?

Answer (score 0):

When you hover on an object, *vscode* will show you a small canvas where you can see the type. But for long types, like **zod** for example, you can't see the whole types. But, I find a little *hack*.

It's so simple. You will use the **refactor** action in vscode. So you select the code where you have your variable with a very long type, and you refactor in a new function. So when you do that, vscode write the whole typings for all *meaningfull* **variables** inside your selection.

Happy hack !!!